# When Option pattern matching optimizes up to if statements in Scala?

Tags: scala, optimization, compilation, pattern-matching, bytecode

Here is the `ifA` function for `Option`, written using if-statements:

```scala
def ifA[A](fcond: Option[Boolean])(ifTrue: Option[A], ifFalse: Option[A]): Option[A] =
  if (fcond.isDefined) {
    if (fcond.get) ifTrue
    else ifFalse
  } else None
```

And here is the same function, but if-statements replaced by pattern matching:

```scala
def ifA[A](fcond: Option[Boolean])(ifTrue: Option[A], ifFalse: Option[A]): Option[A] =
  fcond match
    case Some(true) => ifTrue
    case Some(false) => ifFalse
    case None => None
```

The first one is more optimized, as I can see from the bytecode, compiled with godbolt with `scalac-3.0.0`, [link to compiled](https://godbolt.org/z/bafjdv1dM).

I want to write code like the second, but not loosing performance. So, are there any jvm's, that optimizes the second code up to first one? And is there any difference between this code compiled with `scalac-3.0.0` and newer versions of `scalac`?

Comment: Looking at the byte code is not a definite answer to performance. Did you actually run a benchmark on these 2 methods? With JMH for instance.

Comment: Given how aggressive graal is at inlining, I'd not be _that_ surprised to see `fcond.flatMap { cond => if (cond) ifTrue else ifFalse }` end up being something at least as performant as `ifA`.

Comment: _"but not loosing performance"_ do you even know if the minimal difference matters at all?

Answer (score 1):

As comments have mentioned, bytecode terseness does not necessarily translate to performance (although it will have some bearing on it). This is because of techniques such as Just-In-Time (JIT) compiling to machine code that can be done by the JVM during runtime for "hot" parts of the code.

The best way to understand what is faster is to measure with a tool like [jmh](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh). For convenience building and benchmarking in Scala, there is a plugin for sbt called [sbt-jmh](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-jmh) that can be used. To benchmark various JVMs you would need to cleanly compile and run your benchmarks in each.

Curiously, the behaviour you've posted could also be expressed in another way:

```scala
def ifF[A](fcond: Option[Boolean])(ifTrue: Option[A], ifFalse: Option[A]): Option[A] =
    fcond.flatMap { cond =>
        if (cond) ifTrue else ifFalse
    }
```

Which results in even shorter bytecode than the first option, and is at least as Scala idiomatic as your second option.